# TensorFlow 2.0 & TensorFlow Hub: load_module_spec equivalent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

When using TensorFlow 1.x and TensorFlow hub we can load a module's spec to inspect the expected output shape (and probably other useful specifications too!) like this:

```
spec = hub.load_module_spec("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")
shape = spec.get_output_info_dict()['default'].get_shape()
```

When trying to do the same with a TF 2.0 compatible hub module I hit the following error message on calling `load_module_spec`:

> Missing implementation that supports:
>   loader(*('/tmp/tfhub_modules/82c4aaf4250ffb09088bd48368ee7fd00e5464fe',),
>   **{})

Is there an alternative means of inspecting a TF 2.0 hub module's output shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TensorFlow 2, TF Hub will switch to shipping TF2's native object-based SavedModels [[doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/saved_model), [RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20181116-saved-model.md)]. These are loaded by `tf.saved_model.load()` if already on your filesystem, or `hub.load()` with optional download from a URL. That gives you a restored `Trackable` object with a `__call__` member that behaves like a `@tf.function`, meaning it has one or more concrete functions, each backed by a TF graph, and dispatches between them based on Tensor shapes/dtypes and non-Tensor arguments.

With the current alpha version of TF2, if you know the permissible TensorSpec for inputs, you can drill down to the outputs like:

```py
loaded_model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim128/1")
concrete_function = loaded_model.__call__.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec((None,), tf.string))
print(concrete_function.output_shapes, ":",
      concrete_function.output_dtypes)
```

That gives me

```
(None, 128) : <dtype: 'float32'>
```